How to rewrite a php file name in .htaccess [mod_rewrite]
Pardon, have not done any html/css/php since my early childhood. Now 15+ years later decided to tinker with it for fun.
Could anyone explain how do I rewrite a simple URL through .htaccess? I have almost zero experience with .htaccess.
For instance:
localhost/test.php to localhost/test/ or something similar in order not to expose how the real php file is named (in this case test.php)
or
"domain"/test.php to "domain"/test/ or something similar in order not to expose how the real php file is named (in this case test.php)
All my php files and .htaccess are located in the AppServ “www” directory, not complicating life with extra folders.
Thank you all in advance!
Found the existing tutorials quite complicated with many folders, different rewrite patterns etc.

Recommend asking chat GPT, it will help you step through the steps and help debug as you progress.
